# Targeting the value of array items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of values and I want to create another array where I can define a value based on these values. For example:

My array:

```
var val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

New array I would like:

```
[red, green, blue, black]
```

I have tried a for-loop like this:

```js
var val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var color = [];

for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  if (val < 200) {
    color += "green";
  } else if (val.value > '200') {
    color += "blue";
  } else {
    color += "grey"
  }
}

console.log(color);
```

But at the moment it is bringing back only grey. I don't think I am targeting the value of the array items correctly

EDIT: Didnt expect so many comments etc so quickly! I tried to demonstrate my issue but did not provide real content and in the process messed up a bit of my example, apologies.

Adam thank you for your answer, I didn't realise I missed the [i] inside to loop. I changed my loop to this and it is working now:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
            if (val[i] < 200) {
                color+="green";
            }else if (val[i] < 300){
                color+="blue";
            }else{
                color+="grey"
            }
        }
```

EDIT 2, it works to a degree. Though to get it inside an array I used the push method as explained by 31piy.

Comment: What is `val` ?

Comment: Please read the documentation concerning strings and compare that to arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String ; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array

Comment: FYI `color+="green";` should be `color.push('green')` or `color.push(green)` if `green` is a variable

Comment: Why do you use `val` in the first statement then `val.value` in the `else if`?

Comment: Start by learning the basics of arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays. Almost every line of your current code is wrong.

Comment: Is it  "if (val,value < 200) {"

Comment: you need `if(val[i] < 200)`. also you need `200` in your else if and not `'200'`. `color[i] = "grey" to make that index equal a color

Comment: what is the relation of `1 ... 4` and the colors? what is a value of 200 doing here?

Comment: Please unselect the answer you selected as correct and fix your solution to an actual...correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an item to the array, you most-probably would use `push` method. Plus, you're not using the `i` to fetch the indexed item of the array.

```js
var val = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var color = [];

for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  if (val[i] < 200) {
    color.push("green");
  } else if (val[i] > '200') {
    color.push("blue");
  } else {
    color.push("grey");
  }
}

console.log(color);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never using the index you are defining in your loop.

```js
var color = [];
var val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
    if (val[i] < 200) {
        color+="green";
    }else if (val[i] > 200){
        color+="blue";
    }else{
        color+="grey"
    }
}
console.log(color);
```

This is a solution to fix the issue with accessing your loops, which the original question seems to ask for. There are other issues in the code you will need to solve.

Comment: Good solution. Turns color from an array to a string of "greengreengreengreen". I would probably have pushed the "Run code snippet" to test it before a.) finalizing the solution b.) accepting it as a right answer.

Comment: The title of this post is literally "Targeting the value or array items". The code snippet shows how to target array items in a for loop. The OP obviously found it helpful since they marked it as a solution.

Comment: OP wanted a return Array of colors...clearly stated as "New array I would like: [red, green, blue, black]". Please explain to SO how your solution provides that fulfillment to the entirety as requested. The title is a lead into what the issue is....that is why OP can add test cases, comments, etc. Just as Stack Overflow is the title of the site...there are contents within it rather than overloading a stack. Common sense kicks in somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps you could have written your own answer instead of complaining in comments on this post, the intention of the site is to help users not to harass others because you don't like their answer.

Comment: Thank you Adam for that last comment. Its a learning process. People make mistakes. On here you seem to get ripped a new one if your question is with errors, be them overlooked or unknown.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over an array you need to access the elements of the array directly `val[i] < 200` not the array itself `val < 200`.

Same for the target array `color` you need to assign the value to the intended index of the array i.e: `color[i]` though `color.push()` works too.

Your `color` array now contains only `green` as all values were below 200.

I updated your source array for all conditions.

```js
var val = [199, 200, 201]
var color = [];

for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  if (val[i] < 200) {
    color[i] = "green";
  } else if (val[i] > 200) {
    color[i] = "blue";
  } else {
    color[i] = "grey"
  }
}

console.log(color);
```

You can shorten this if you wish, using the [**Ternary Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and you can use `.push()` as well as others suggested.

```js
var val = [199, 200, 201]
var colors = [];
var value;

for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  value = val[i];
  color = value < 200 ? 'green' : value > 200 ? 'blue' : 'grey';

  colors.push(color);
}

console.log(colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use the .push method if I understand your problem correctly. Also you'll need to reference the values using the index of the array like so:

```
var val = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var color = [];

for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  if (val[i] < 200) {
    color.push("green");
  } else if (val[i] > '200') {
    color.push("blue");
  } else {
    color.push("grey");
  }
}

console.log(color);
```

That should sort out both the problem of accessing the array correctly and pushing the values into the new array.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the code a bit, I'm using a [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop as they look a bit nicer, I've also changed it so you're pushing the values to the array rather than appending them as strings.

```js
const vals = [100, 200, 300];

let color = [];
for (let val of vals) {
  if (val < 200) {
    color.push("green");
  } else if (val > 200) {
    color.push("blue");
  } else {
    color.push("grey");
  }
}
console.log(color);
```